# Display CountDown Timer in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

**I have a Form and a CountDown Timer .I have some problems :**

1. How can I display a CountDown Timer as : Hour : Minute : Second in asp.net mvc . When CountDown Timer (Hour=00 , Minute=00 , Second=00) , Form auto submit data.
2. I have a Table in SQL with 2 columns : Name (nvarchar(250)) ; **Minute (int)**.
   How can I load column Minute to CountDown Timer from SQL?

Hope , Everyone can help me!
Thanks

Comment: the answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023424/the-best-way-to-refresh-my-aspx-site-with-a-timer-in-c) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a jquery plugin for this. There are many out there. [Here's one](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) you could use. It has [callbacks](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) like for example `onExpiry` which is triggered when the timer reaches zero so that you could submit the form.

Comment: Thank!How can I load column Minute in SQL to CountDown Timer?. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: @quantt, what data access technology are you using?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I am using LINQ TO SQL

Comment: @quantt, you could have the controller action query a repository which will return the corresponding value from the database (using Linq to SQL) and then pass this value to the view.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Before I pass value to the view , this value have data type : DateTime ?

Comment: @quantt, not necessary. It could be a string as well. From what I can see in the documentation of the plugin there are many different ways to configure a starting and ending values.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Because it is running on client side, Is it possible that user can hack it and stop the Timer.?